getting access denied error in launching chrome browser inside docker container
I am trying to run the playwright browser inside a custom docker container. In the docker image, have installed all the necessary browsers in the path /tmp/pwbrowsers/ and set the required permission. Verified the browsers are installed inside the image manually.
The issue is when running the 'mvn clean test' , i am getting an EACCES error.
I have tried running a sample typescript test with the browsers in the same location /tmp/pwbrowsers and its working fine. Only the issue is occuring with Playwright java.
Please let me know if anyone come across this situation and found any solution.
Caused by: com.microsoft.playwright.impl.DriverException: Error { message='Failed to launch: Error: spawn /tmp/pwbrowsers EACCES name='Error stack='Error: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /tmp/pwbrowsers EACCES
